# SQL table with primary key over two columns and unique values in both columns

Tags: sql, database-design, constraints, primary-key

How to create a table in SQL with the following attributes?

- The table has two columns A and B.
- The primary key of the table is (A, B).
- All values in A are unique. Pseudo code: (Count(A) == COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT A)).
- All values in B are also unique.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable(
    A VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, -- A HAS DISTINCT VALUES
    B VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL              -- B HAS DISTINCT VALUES
);

INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('A1', 'B1') --> Add value
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('A1', 'B2') --> Do not add value
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('A2', 'B2') --> Add value
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('A3', 'B3') --> Add value
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('A4', 'B3') --> Do not add value
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('A4', 'B4') --> Add value
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('A5', 'B6') --> Add value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a compound PRIMARY KEY:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    A VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    B VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_AB primary key (A,B),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_A UNIQUE(A),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_B UNIQUE(B)
);
```

Please note: a table with just 2 columns with both columns in the primary key smells funny.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful. Why do two columns as primary keys smell funny? How would you design the table? I don't understand why the question was closed...

Comment: For the understanding... I want to save ISIN numbers in column 1 and Stock Tickers in column 2. I only want to save one stock ticker for exactly one ISIN.

Comment: I've voted to re-open. I voted to close initially because I mis-read your question. apologies